# requestLocationUpdates for count traveled meters

Tags: java, android, android-gps

UPDATE:
My real class looks like this and it works (it toast me dis variable from onLocationChange method). But I cant reach this variable in MainActivity - it always throw me 0.0 - Is it possible that this class destroy this variable at some time?

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener {

    Context context;
    double plat;
    double plon;
    double clat;
    double clon;

    public double dis;

    public GPStracker(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public Location getlocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSenabled;
        isGPSenabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSenabled) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return location;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Proszę włączyć GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        clat = location.getLatitude();
        clon = location.getLongitude();
        if (clat != plat || clon != plon) {
            dis += getDistance(plat, plon, clat, clon);
            plat = clat;
            plon = clon;

            setDis(dis);
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(dis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
        double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
        double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB - lonA)) +
                (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
        double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
        double dist = ang * 6371;
        return dist;
    }

    public double getDis() {
        return dis;
    }

    public void setDis(double dis) {
        this.dis = dis;
    }
}
```

I'd like to ask (maybe thats a stupid question), but i'm trying to count meters of travel using gps provider. And right now i'm thinnking about use requestLocationUpdates maybe in this way:

```
int i;      
      requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
and 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
i++
}
```

So according to google references, it should auto update my int i every new one meter. Thats right? Or maybe i think wrong? Thats looks so easy to count meters of travel but i'm not sure will it work and whether it will be accurate... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should use example:
`loc1.distanceTo(loc2);`

Answer (score 0):

With the below code:

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
```

`requestLocationUpdates` is being called every 1 sec and 1 meter distance covered. As a result, you are getting updated location in every call. You can calculate the distance between previous location and new location and add it to `distance` as below to get total traveled distance.

You can compare Try out the below code:

```
 Location previousLoc = null;
 float distance = 0;
 boolean firstTime = true;
 publc void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if(firstTime){
          previousLoc = location;
          firstTime = false;
      }
      distance += previousLoc.distanceTo(location);
      previousLoc = location;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you have to use `setDis()` ? `dis`'s value is changing in `onLocationChanged()` anyway. I would suggest you to implement `LocationListener` to your activity.

Comment: And do it in same class as MainActivity? It's very strange, even if i use your example it throw me 0.

Comment: If you want to use GPS tracker class, then you have to create a `LocationListener` in activity then apply it in `GPSTracker`. You also have to call `requestLocationUpdates` from activity. Or you can use `BroadcastReceiver` to notify your activity that your location is changed.